# continue running if user input is not detected

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

here i have written a simple program to get user input

```
    Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Satisfied? yes or no: ");
    String decision = keyInput.nextLine();

    if(decision.matches("no"){
      
        //code
        
    } else {
        
        keyInput.close();

        //code
    }
```

how would i make it so that it jumps to the else statement if no user input is detected after 10 seconds?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer & TimerTask like so:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

...

TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
    public void run()
    {
        if( str.equals("") )
        {
            System.out.println( "you input nothing. exit..." );
            System.exit( 0 );
        }
    }    
};

...

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule( task, 10*1000 );

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String in = sc.readLine();

timer.cancel();
```